# How Do I Create a complete String from ArrayList

Tags: string, loops, for-loop, arraylist

I want to create a `String` from an `ArrayList`. Currently, I am only able to return the last value from the `ArrayList`. My code:

```
eachstep = new ArrayList<String>();
for (int i = 0; i < parsedsteps.size(); i++) {
eachstep.add(parsedsteps.get(i).replaceAll("<[^>]*>", ""));
}                   
for (int i = 0; i < eachstep.size(); i++) {
    String directions = i + "."+" "+eachstep.get(i)+"\n"+;
}
```

Gives me:

```
3.  This is step 3.
```

Instead of:

```
1. This is step 1.          
2. This is step 2.
3. This is step 3.
```

How do I make my for loop create a `String` with all the values from the `ArrayList`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to declare your string outside of the loop, and I suggest using [StringBuilder](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/StringBuilder.html) as well, it's more efficient for building strings like this.

```
StringBuilder directions = new StringBuilder();
for( int i = 0; i < eachstep.size(); i++ )
{
    directions.append( i + "." + " " + eachstep.get( i ) + "\n" );
}
```

Then when you want to get the string out of the StringBuilder, just call `directions.toString()`.

Answer (score 0):

```
String directions = "";
for (int i = 0; i < eachstep.size(); i++) {
    directions += i + "."+" "+eachstep.get(i)+"\n";
}
```

Comment: sorry, without the + at the end

Comment: Stringbuilder would be better

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
   eachstep = new ArrayList<String>();
   for (int i = 0; i < parsedsteps.size(); i++) {
       eachstep.add(parsedsteps.get(i).replaceAll("<[^>]*>", ""));
   }
   String directions="";
   for (int i = 0; i < eachstep.size(); i++) {
       directions += i + "."+" "+eachstep.get(i)+"\n"+;
   }
```

If you have large size of string array, you might want to consider using StringBuilder, e.g

```
  StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
  for(String str: eachstep ){
       builder.append(i).append(".").append(str).append("\n");
  }
  String direction = builder.toString();
```